# Android Studio not deploying to phone for debug with local path does't exist error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've been trying to port an eclipse project over to android studio with little luck. The project includes action bar sherlock and a couple of other dependencies.

At the moment if I compile, make or rebuild my project everything goes smoothly - but if I attempt to run my project I just get an error saying "Local path doesn't exist." - which is referring to the location my apk file should be - if I go to that location, the whole apk directory doesnt exist.

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that whilst the ide wasn't giving me any error messages, if I ran

```
gradlew packageDebug
```

in the project root it gave me some errors relating to android-support-v4

After resolving these errors it then produced the apk and therefore allowed deployment to the phone

Answer (score 4):

Matt Whetton's answer helped me find my solution so I up-voted that too. In my case, running from the command line said it could not find the SDK path because I didn't have a local.properties file. I added in the local.properties file with the appropriate "sdk.dir" variable set, and now it works.

What I actually did was create a new project in Android Studio and then copied the local.properties file it automatically created to make certain it matched.

I hope this helps someone who has the same problem.